# how to get data in a single row in database search

Tags: php, mysql, database

i want to to get the data from my database table games.
i searched as

```
SELECT team_id,result from games where team_id=17;
```

In games table i have results of all matchs such as

```
id     team_id team    result
21       17    India   w
22       17    India   l
23       17    India   l
24       17    India   w
```

all i want to get this data as

```
team_id  result1 result2 result3 result4
  17      w      l      l       w
```

If anyone have idea how could i do it?

Comment: Do you have another table for teams?

Comment: Google : `MySQL Pivoting`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 0):

For a limited number of results, say up to 4, you could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT team_id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN result END) AS result1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN result END) AS result2, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN result END) AS result3, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN result END) AS result4 
FROM (
  SELECT team_id, result,
         @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rn
  FROM games 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS vars
  WHERE team_id = 17
  ORDER BY id) AS t
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it is a limited amount of results..

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mysql group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get all the results in a field with comas, maybe this helps you too...

Answer (score 0):

A "dirty" (but rather general - in that it is not limited by the number of results) way of doing that would be:

```
SELECT team_id, GROUP_CONCAT(result) AS results FROM GAMES ...
```

So that `results` will contain `w,l,l,w`. Then (I noticed you tagged the post using 'php'), you may use something along the lines of [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get an array out of the result

```
$results = explode(',', $row[1]);
```